# max-height: fit-content; not working as expected in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, mozilla

This style works for e.g. chrome.

```
p.ex1 {
    max-height: fit-content;
    height: 250px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The intention is to use the whole height, with scrolling, if necessary,
but shrink height to fit content if the content is small.
However, how is this accomplished in Firefox?

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dim_max-height

### chrome:

[image: chrome]

### firefox:

[image: firefox]

Comment: I use FireFox Dev edition v61 and I get the same result!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height - `fit-content` is experimental and not supported in many browsers.  I would use flex instead

Comment: why not use `max-height: 250px` and default `auto` height (which is exactly the content height) instead?

Comment: @Pete max-content is not, but gives the same result. I could use that, but I still need the answer.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn This is just an example. My case uses calc and is dynamic. The question is still valid anyway.

Comment: @Hawk according to the link it is

Comment: also not listed as one of the official properties on w3c: https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/max-height

Comment: @Pete You are correct. In my mind I read "use max-content instead"

Answer (score 17):

Try Using:

```
p.ex1 {
    max-height: fit-content;
    height: -moz-max-content;
    height: 250px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**height: -moz-max-content;**

This tag will work as 'fit-content' for Mozilla.

Answer (score 7):

this is what worked for me:

```
max-height: -moz-max-content;
```